# Travel from London to Paris or Zurich by train without a Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, uk, indian-citizens, eurostar

As an Indian citizen, if I travel through train (Eurostar) from London to either Paris or Zurich, would I require a Schengen visa?

I am on a trip with family to London. We all want to explore some cities of Europe, but we have just applied for UK visas.

Comment: Are you in effect asking if you need a Schengen visa to enter the Schengen area? If so, what is your citizenship?

Comment: I am from India. I have a UK visa . But i read in some relevant post that one could take the eurostar from london to paris without schenegan...and there are security checks nad french immigration. So that is the reason for my doubt.

Comment: So what can I do now ? On the spot arrival visa ? or somethong else...Any suggestions..

Comment: I think the question is actually whether the train is handled in the same way.

Comment: You'll have to apply for a separate visa from a Schengen country Embassy in London. There is no visa on arrival for Indian citizens for the Schengen Area

Answer (score 13):

**Yes of course!, you need a Schengen visa.**

The UK is not a part of the [Schengen Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) despite being a member of the European Union. Ireland shares the same opinion as the UK due to the [Common Travel Area](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Travel_Area) agreement between both.

Thus, having a UK visa is not enough to travel to the Schengen Area and vice versa. You will still need to apply for a Schengen visa in order to take the Eurostar from London to Paris or Zurich.

Comment: Is the same true for the other way around? does a EU/Schengen citizen that wants to visit the UK require a UK visa?

Comment: @NateKerkhofs do you mean a non-EU citizen with a non-UK visa? Because EU citizens do not need a visa to travel to the UK at all.

Comment: @NateKerhofs We are talking about *residents*, EU *citizens*, whether from the UK or elsewhere can visit all EU countries (and more) without a visa.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was just asking because I can't remember if I needed a visa to take the Channel Tunnel train from Calais to Dover. And since it was related to the current question, I thought it didn't warrant to make an additional question.

Answer (score 6):

Road, train or sea travel is supposed to be handled exactly in the same way than air travel, with a border check when entering the Schengen area. As an Indian citizen, you will therefore need to have a Schengen visa and to have your passport stamped. In any case, finding a way into the area (say over some mountain road, with a private craft, or something) does not exempt you from any of the legal requirements to enter it.

In the case of Eurostar, there is in fact a full airport-like check before boarding the train, see [Train passport control from London to Paris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34217/train-passport-control-from-london-to-paris)

Comment: Even if you found a way how to cross the Schengen boundary without a border control, it would be illegal to enter if you need a visa and you don't have it.

Comment: @tohecz That's what the third sentence of my answer means or am I missing something?