# Im travelling to London from India i wanted to visit paris but i only have uk visa is possible to travel with out visa to paris from london

Tags: uk

I have only UK visa but wanted to travel to paris is it possible with only uk cisa to travel to paris . I heard that we can travel to paris from london without visa

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: If the OP is an Indian citizen, it may be a closer duplicate of [Travel from London to Paris or Zurich by train without a Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/34246/19560)