# Can a minor travel to the UK with an adult but return alone?

Tags: uk, pakistani-citizens, minors

I am 13 years old and have an accompanied visa with my aunt.

Can I enter the UK with my aunt and then return back to Pakistan alone (without her or with any other adult) if my aunts name is on MY visa?

Comment: Which airline are you travelling with?

Comment: Gender? Given your destination, the question has gender specific implications.

Comment: oh- i just forgot to mention this that my AUNTS name is ON MY VISA...so then can i travel ALONE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will readily presume your family is OK with this idea. It is not our place to speculate on that.

Despite what @GayotFow indicates I can't find any gender specific information. The only airline flying London-Islamabad direct, Pakistan Airlines [Conditions of Carriage](http://www.piac.com.pk/PIA_PolicynTerms/COC.pdf) says:

> 7.7.1 You will not be accepted for carriage if you are under 5 years of age on the date the flight
>   commences unless you are accompanied by an escort aged 18 years or more. If you are between
>   5 and 16 years of age, we can arrange for an escort, provided we receive 7 Days or more notice
>   prior to travel and an extra charge is paid.

Nothing else in the CoC is about this age range, 7.7.2 only applies to 5-12 year olds.

I would strongly recommend to arrange such an escort. If something goes sideways, you don't want a 13 year old to deal with it alone.

Another airline which specifically mentions Pakistan is [Jet Airways](http://www.jetairways.com/EN/CA/ProductAndServices/UnaccompaniedMinors.aspx) but only in regards of being a short haul flight for them, no gender specific restriction.

In general, without knowing the specific airline, the above is typical: above 12 the UAM service is optional but strongly recommended.

Comment: If it's an accompanied visa, isn't the named adult REQUIRED to travel with the child?

Comment: On the way back? Visas are required to enter and stay.

Comment: Does it mean the UK has no responsibility when a child leaves the UK unaccompanied?

Comment: The UK has no form of exit immigration control, last I checked so where would a visa enter the picture? Also, I thought the chain of events is that the adult hands over the minor to the airline with the UAM service and so the minor is never unaccompanied.

Comment: Next week, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43808/is-the-uk-planning-to-introduce-exit-checks-in-2015  But also read Section 55 of the 2009 Act.  Also Google 'uk paladin team' etc etc

Comment: For the gender part, look in chat :)