# Can I enter Canada and return to the UK using different passports?

Tags: air-travel, uk, passports, canada, international-travel

I am a dual British/Canadian with a passport from each nation. Can I use the Canadian passport to enter/leave Canada and the British passport to leave/return to the UK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes you can.**

Canada has no exit checks. Britain has recently instituted them, but I see no sign that they will require you to exit on a British passport (they don't require you to enter on a British passport). Neither have a problem with you being a dual citizen. And either passport will get you visa-free access to the other country. [This question gives you more general advice on using two passports](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel), but in this case it's not a big deal. Show either one whenever. The only place where it makes a difference is coming to Britain, where showing your British passport gets you in the fast immigration line. (Strangely there is no equivalent benefit in Canada).

Comment: oops, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/43808/is-the-uk-planning-to-introduce-exit-checks-in-2015/43838#43838  can you edit your answer?

Comment: from what I understand Britain also does not have exit checks for air travel

Comment: As of September 29, 2016 Canadian dual citizens will be required to enter Canada using their Canadian passport if travelling by air. http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/dual-canadian-citizens.asp This doesn't change your answer, but is worth noting, since it didn't use to be the case.