# Travelling from London to Paris on a Schengen visa issued by Switzerland

Tags: visas, schengen

I see this has been answered in the past but I want to check if it is the same nowadays. I have a UK visa and a Schengen visa issued by the Swiss embassy.

We're traveling to London and then taking the Eurostar to Paris. We have confirmed bookings of hotels and flights. Paris to Nice, and then Nice to Geneva.

Would it be a problem in London to board the Eurostar?

A relative of mine was refused a connecting flight on Turkish Airlines from Turkey to an EU country that did not issue the Schengen visa, hence asking.

Comment: Could you add a link to the earlier answer? How long ago was it?

Comment: I would be curious do have the full story of that relative of yours. Plenty of people enter the Schengen area via a country different from the one which issued the visa, as this is most definitely allowed, as long as you meet the original conditions for the visa. I suspect there was something else going on.

Comment: @jcaron Turkish Ground Handling and Pegasus Ground Handling staff are notoriously incompetent, so so surprise at all. As a lot don't speak English, they're rarely even going to bother checking TIMATIC, let alone in great detail, instead acting on their personal presumptions about the rules

Comment: @jcaron Flying from NewYork to Riga by Turkish air but was stopped at immigration because schegen was issued by Italian embassy. They ended up paying extra to fly to milan and then got another flight to Riga.

Comment: @OzairAbbas Makes no sense. If she flew Turkish, that means she flew New York-Istanbul-Riga. You say she was "refused a connecting flight on Turkish Airlines", which means she was refused Boarding on the Istanbul-Riga flight, but also that she was "stopped by Immigration", which would mean she was refused entry to Latvia and sent back. Which one is it?

Comment: @user16259 
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/34217/train-passport-control-from-london-to-paris
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa

Comment: @coke, sorry, not immigration, it was turkish airline staff not issuing boarding pass. They said riga will not allow entry ... and they will have to fly back and pay fines etc ... 

I Contacted French Embassy and they have confirmed there shouldn't be any issue entering France when schengen is issued by Another member state

Comment: @OzairAbbas Like I said then, it's Turkish Airlines Ground Handling staff that were incompetent, and this specific thing happens a lot with them. I would write a complaint to them if I were you, to prevent this from Happening to others. to ata@tgs.aero with a copy to info@tgs.aero. Explain in Detail (incl when it happened) that your relative was refused to board a flight to Riga with an Italian visa because they thought you Need to get a Schengen visa from the first Point of entry, when that's only the case if there's no main Destination. The main Destination was Italy, hence the Italian visa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eurostar doesn't check visas; that'll be up to French police in London.

As such, if you can prove Switzerland is your main destination, you should have no problems (and I doubt the French will even care - they rarely do)